# Entity Framework, how to avoid serializing my whole database when there is a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, serialization, entity-framework-6

I am using entity framework in a .NET Framework 4.6.1 API project.

I have a database with 3 tables like so :

[image: Simple MCD]

When serializing my entities to JSON, everything is fine on the left side, but because I have a many-to-many relationship on the right side (The 3 could be replaced with n), and C can contain many different Bs, I end up, when trying to retrieve a single A Serializing the A's Bs and thus, the Bs' Cs, which in turn serializes pretty much my whole database when, really, I just want a single entity.

The problem is even worse when getting the whole collection of As, as it serializes my database multiple times, making it very slow and memory inefficient.

I have the following bit of code as reference handling :

```
config
    .Formatters
    .JsonFormatter
    .SerializerSettings
    .PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
```

Can't find anything related or similar to that problem anywhere on the web.

Comment: Show us your EF query.

Comment: @MickyD Querry here is irrelevant as it is a simple return of the db.A.

Comment: Use projection to build a view of the data suitable for serialization. This can be to DTOs (ideally) or `.Select(x => new A { /* populate fields and related data */ })` As a general rule you typically don't want to expose all aspects of your data domain model to consumers so it is generally better to create a DTO with just the details that are applicable and project to those.

Comment: @StevePy That Sounds like a possible solution. Adding a lot of intermediaries inbetween the application and web service though. That also requires the web service controllers to use the DTOs instead of the entity model, no ?

Comment: The issues with passing entities is that you aren't really passing the entity, rather a detached copy, and when deserialized you can easily end up with multiple references to the same data row which leads to further errors/problems. Defining DTOs lets you shape the transmitted data down to just what is necessary, saving space/bandwidth. Tools like Automapper can make projecting to DTOs, (`ProjectTo<TDto>()`) and copying values from DTOs into loaded entities (`Map(Dto, Entity)`) a trivial matter compared to hand-writing Selects and copying values between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use DTO or change JSON converter setting like below

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All,
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
};
```